# Python: write multiple str.format() lines to a file?

Tags: python

```
for host in platforms:
    f = open(host, 'w')
    f.write('define host {\n')
    f.write('    host_name            {}\n'.format(host))
    f.write('    alias                {}\n'.format(host))
    f.write('    display_name         {}\n'.format(host))
    f.write('    address              {}\n'.format(str(socket.gethostbyname(host))))
    f.write('    use                  linux-server\n')
    f.write('    register             1\n')
    f.write('}\n')
```

Is there a better way? Is there a simple way to format all these string but only do one write method call? If the above is considered best practice that's fine, just seems like it could be prettier some other way.

Comment: The socket.gethostbyname will be placed inside a try suite later. ;)

Comment: you may be able to do with space padding through string formatting directly, instead of hardcoding it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use named substitutions in a long, triple-quoted string.

```
def print_host(host, address):
    f = open(host, 'w')
    f.write("""define host {{
        host_name            {host}
        alias                {host}
        display_name         {host}
        address              {address}
        use                  linux-server
        register             1
    }}\n""".format(host=host, address=address))

print_host("myhost", "10.10.10.10")
```

But note that you must double your curly braces to escape them here.

Comment: This is great to know and you certainly answered my question. After modifying the script to use this format I ended up reverting back as the additional complexity didn't make the script any easier to read or edit. I'm sure I"ll make use of this in the future though!

Answer (score 0):

Triple-quoted strings.

```
f.write('''{} {}
{}'''.format(1, 2, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You ended up reverting back... Would you prefer one of these possibilities ? :

```
def print_host(host,serv,numb, ch = ('define host {{\n'
                                     '    {0:<21}{6}\n'
                                     '    {1:<21}{6}\n'
                                     '    {2:<21}{6}\n'
                                     '    {3:<21}{7}\n'
                                     '    {4:<21}{8}\n'
                                     '    {5:<21}{9}\n'
                                     '}}\n'            ) ):

    f = open(host, 'w')
    f.write(ch.format('host_name','alias','display_name',
                      'address','use','register',
                      host,
                      str(socket.gethostbyname(host)),serv,numb))
```

or

```
def print_host(host,serv,numb):

    tu = ('define host {',
          '    {:<21}{}'.format('host_name',host),
          '    {:<21}{}'.format('alias',host),
          '    {:<21}{}'.format('display_name',host),
          '    {:<21}{}'.format('address',str(socket.gethostbyname(host))),
          '    {:<21}{}'.format('use',serv),
          '    {:<21}{}'.format('register',numb),
          '}\n')

    f = open(host, 'w')
    f.write('\n'.join(tu))
```

or

```
def print_host(host,serv,numb):
    f = open(host, 'w')
    f.writelines(('define host {\n',
                  '    {:<21}{}\n'.format('host_name',host),
                  '    {:<21}{}\n'.format('alias',host),
                  '    {:<21}{}\n'.format('display_name',host),
                  '    {:<21}{}\n'.format('address',str(socket.gethostbyname(host))),
                  '    {:<21}{}\n'.format('use',serv),
                  '    {:<21}{}\n'.format('register',numb),
                  '}\n'))
```

or ( I prefer this neater one)

```
def print_host(host,serv,numb):
    f = open(host, 'w')
    f.writelines(('define host {\n',
                  '    host_name            {}\n'.format(host),
                  '    alias                {}\n'.format(host),
                  '    display_name         {}\n'.format(host),
                  '    address              {}\n'.format(str(socket.gethostbyname(host))),
                  '    use                  {}\n'.format(serv),
                  '    register             {}\n'.format(numb),
                  '}\n'))
```